# QGraphicsItems are rendered outside QgraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have created a Qt Gui Application that, amongst other panels, contains a `QGraphicsView`. Now my problem is that the `QGraphicsItems` are seemingly artefactually rendered outside the view, and I haven't been able to figure out the reason.

See an example image here

[image]

In case it helps, all my QObjects/QWidgets are stacked as follows:

- MainWindow, inherits QMainWindow

  - QSplitter

    - QSplitter

      - QSplitter

        - QTabWidget

          - QStackedWidget

            - MyEditor, inherits QGraphicsView

              - QGraphicsScene

but also with a more minimal example without the splitters and tabwidget, the problem persists. In my search for a solution, I found that calling `viewport()->update();` in the QGraphicsView resolves similar rendering issues within the QGraphicsScene, but not outside.

I found only a partial solution: I noticed that the entire application is updated when the window is deactivated (i.e. when you click/Alt-Tab to another program), a `QEvent::WindowDeactivate`. This seems to trigger a cascading `update()` for all widgets in the application. Indeed, calling `update()` solves the problem for the space between panels, but not for the panels themselves. I haven't found a method that updates panels cascadingly.

So my question is:

- Is it a bug or am I horribly abusing `QGraphicsScene`?
- Is there a general fix to this problem? And what could be the cause?
- A potential solution might be to extend QWidget, in order to implement a cascading update. But it feels like that's not solving the root of the problem.

I use Qt 5.8.0. This problem persists at least on Mac and Windows.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In your place I would suspect there can be something wrong in the way your graphicsitem are painted, it seems like they are always painted completely even if sometimes the graphicsScene only needs a tiny bit. So maybe (I am thinking loud) there is an event calling a paint function with some coordinates and the paint function is ignoring the coordinates and always repainting itself fully.